# Multiple/split filter chains for a single Solr field

Tags: solr, search-engine

Is it possible to configure a Solr field to have multiple/split Filter chains?  For example, could I create a Filter chain that looks like this?:

```
        StandardTokenizer
                ↓
         LowerCaseFilter
          ↙           ↘
  SynonymnFilter   PhoneticFilter    
        ↓
   NGramFilter
```

I've done quite a bit of searching and haven't found any examples of setting up a Filter chain this way.

**EDIT**

The main reason I would like to do this in the context of a single field (as opposed to indexing the data twice using a copy field) is for highlighting.  If I use a copy field to run a different filter chain on the same data, my highlighting results come back like this:

```
"highlighting":{
  "1234": {
    "firstName_phonetic":["<hl>John</hl>"],
    "firstName_ngram":["<hl>John</hl>"]
  }
}
```

This makes consuming the results  a bit more difficult as the consuming app needs to choose which highlighted field to display.  Ideally, I'd get something back like this:

```
"highlighting":{
  "1234": {
    "firstName":["<hl>John</hl>"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of one filter goes to the next filter in the chain. There is no support for "branching".

You'll be implementing this method if you want a custom filter.

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream.incrementToken()
```

This method returns a boolean. You can see an example [here](http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/).

Another possible solution is to use a copyField to combine firstName_phonetic and firstName_ngram into firstName and use hl.fl=firstName

Answer (score 1):

It sounds reasonable just to use copyField and index two different fields, each with its own chain.

But, I guess nothing prevents you from implementing your own MyCustomFilter that does what you need, and you plug that one into your conf.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My main reason for wanting to do this is to maintain field highlighting (I'll add this to my question).  I haven't tried it, but I'm assuming that if a query only matched on the copy field, the original field wouldn't have any highlighting applied?